# how to make a checkbox appear after a photo upload?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

For those familiar with rubygems, I am using CarrierWave to allow photo uploads on my app.

This is the code that I'm using in my View

```
Add a photo:
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
```

How can I make a checkbox appear in my View along with some text above it only IF a photo is selected for upload?

Here's the full post.html.erb View

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @post %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 5, :rows => 5 %>
  </div>
  Add a photo:<br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the post model (relevant part)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :image
  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

and the uploader model

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
     "#{secure_token(10)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
   end

   def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

protected
  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end


end
```

Comment: show your model where you defined the image style and attributes ?

Comment: hmmm I used the CarrierWave rubygem and I only included this part (see updated post) in my Post model

Answer (score 0):

So you could use the condition that checks if the image is selected and then you can append the textbox along with text as like the following:

```
if image.image_url  
 #your checkbox stuff and text stuff
end
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to use: <% if image.image_url.exists? %>, but getting some errors. I posted up the imageuploader model in the updated post. Do you know what the correct image.image_url should be?

Answer (score 0):

you store only one photo per post, you need to store your photos in another table.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :title
 has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :image_cache, :post_id
  belongs_to :post
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

So you can choose which pictures you want to associate with each posts. Found an example here : https://github.com/kdironside/carrierwave-multi-file-upload

Comment: what I was saying was, how can I make the checkbox+text appear right after someone chooses the file to upload, but BEFORE the user clicks "Post"? So the file is not uploaded yet, it has just been selected. Is there a way to do that?